# Receive event value in Form2 to Form1 WinForms

Tags: c#, events, parameters

I have 2 `WinForms` application forms `Form1` and `Form2`, I want send event value `myValue` from `Form2` to `Form1`.

In `Form2` I have function called from event this way `SendVal();`:

```
 private void SendVal()
 {
     Form1 f = new Form1();
     f._rval = _pval;
     f.Show();
 }
```

and `get`:

```
 public string _pval
 {
    get { return myValue; }
 }
```

And `set` in `Form1` to show it in with `label1.Text`:

```
 public string _rval
 {
     set { label1.Text = value; }
 }
```

this method useful if I want send and receive value with `Form1` load, but I'm trying to find method to receive event value from `Form2` to `Form1` application without `Form1` new load.

Comment: Forms are just classes.  Create any public method or property you like in order to send information and data between them.  You will want to hold onto form references though so you arent creating new ones.

Comment: @Ňɏssa Pøngjǣrdenlarp Hello, can you provide some minimal example, I've edited my post, but I'm still trying to figure out with this task, please check

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming your two forms are in the same project.

If one form is the parent of the other then you can pass the instance of each form to the other when the parent creates the child. You could do this with a constructor, a method or a property, doesn't really matter. Then each can set properties on the other any time it wants to.

You could also create a static FormRegistry class with a Form1 property and a Form2 property

```
public static class FormRegistry
{
    public static Form1 Form1 { get; set; }
    public static Form2 Form2 { get; set; }
}
```

In the Load event of each form, register it

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    FormRegistry.Form1 = this;
}
```

In the FormClosing event of each form, clear its registry property.

```
private Form1_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
{
    FormRegistry.Form1 = null;
}
```

and then you can access the instance of the other form any time you want and set its public properties or do whatever you need to:

```
Form1 f1 = FormRegistry.Form1;
if (f1 != null) 
{ 
    f1.Property = value; 
    RefreshFormOrDoOtherStuff();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have been working with WinForms since 2015 and 2016 and I still remember lots of stuff about it. But I stopped learning WinForms because they became deprecated (In my opinion). But I have good C# knowledge and Forms are just classes. Remember loading a Form is also considered as a event because it triggers when it opens. I assume you are running Form2 as the principal one?
Try this:

**Form2**

```
 private void Form2_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SendVal();
    }
    public string _pval { get; set; }

    private void SendVal()
    {
        Form1 f = new Form1();
        _pval = "set the value here";
        f._rval = _pval;
        f.Show();
    }
```

**Form1**

```
 public string _rval { get; set; }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        label1.Text = _rval;
    }
```

Comment: Hello, this method works with same undesired result as example in my post, with each receiving of value loads Form1 again